# How to avoid cache invalidation in Dockerfile for large binary file (Python_Onbuild)

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am downloading 1.6 GB binary compressed file in my dockfile and then unpacking it using gunzip which leads to storing a 3.6 GB file. I do not want it to be repeated all the time as it takes  a lot of time. Its a static file so it should not be downloaded every time I deploy my changes to the server using Jenkins/docker. However, its download every time, I commit changes, and run Jenkins to deploy them.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM python:2.7.13-onbuild

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes apt-utils
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
RUN curl -o - https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz \
 | gunzip > /usr/src/app/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin
```

**UPDATE:**
I changed the dockfile to a simple one as given below:

```
FROM python:2.7.13-onbuild

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN echo "Test Cache"

CMD /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -t 240 -k gevent -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload src.wsgi:app
```

Now if I do not change the code or any other file, this works fine so the command echo `"test cache"` is not repeated. However, as soon as I make any change to any file in the source folder, all my commands after the following steps are repeated which I think copies my source code the docker directory. This should not happen at this stage because it means that all my commands are repeated as soon as I make any commit.

Here is the output when I do no make any changes to the code and run the build for second time:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  239.1kB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:2.7.13-onbuild
# Executing 3 build triggers...
Step 1/1 : COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
Step 1/1 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache


Step 1/1 : COPY . /usr/src/app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 1911c6dc9fce

Step 2/6 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4019b029d05c
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a99833e908c
Step 4/6 : RUN echo "Test Cache"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 488a62aa1b09
```

Here is the output where I make a single change to one of the source files and you can see that the echo "test cache" is repeated.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  239.1kB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:2.7.13-onbuild
# Executing 3 build triggers...
Step 1/1 : COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
Step 1/1 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache


 Step 1/1 : COPY . /usr/src/app
     ---> 6fd1003e246a
    Removing intermediate container f25a4d2910cf
    Step 2/6 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
     ---> Running in ff324f381875
     ---> 3694086a2b6a
    Removing intermediate container ff324f381875
    Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
     ---> 5f23ab9a15df
    Removing intermediate container 0b0d796f97d0
    Step 4/6 : RUN echo "Test Cache"
     ---> Running in 296d2f141015
    Test Cache
     ---> f90c7708d9eb
```

Comment: Can you paste your build log here ?

Comment: @WassimDhif I cannot put all the logs here because that will be too much but I can just put the relevant one for this specific command. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All my commands were repeating because I was using `python:2.7.13-onbuild` as a base image. It's [docker-file](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/d3c5f47b788adb96e69477dadfb0baca1d97f764/2.7/jessie/onbuild/Dockerfile) looks like this:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ONBUILD COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
ONBUILD RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/app
```

As I was using this as the base image, the copy command is executed before all commands in my docker file and this copy command changes the context every time I make any change in the source code.

I was recommended to use Python:2.7 as a base image directly so I have more control over this copy operation. My new docker-file is as follows with the copy command at the end which solved the issue.

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes apt-utils
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
RUN curl -o - https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz \
 | gunzip > /usr/src/app/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

According to this [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/), the use of Python_onbuild image is generally discouraged.

This explanation is inspired by the answer of my other question on the same issue:
[Which Python variant to use as a base image in dockerfiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421386/which-python-variant-to-use-as-a-base-image-in-dockerfiles)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that the metadata for the context files changes at each build, since you are running it in a Jenkins pipeline. Because of that, the docker build command is not able to use its cache.

What you could try to do is put this large file on the Jenkins machine, and then reference the local file in the Dockerfile. This way you won't have to redownload it at each build.

Comment: Not sure if thats a good practice because that way I can put the file on my production server and would avoid downloading it. It also means that all my docker file commands are repeated every time I run a build process. Isnt there is a workaround for it because it kind of makes the whole caching concept useless in Jenkins.

Comment: Can you confirm that all your Dockerfile instructions doesn't use the cache ? Try a dummy one at the start, something like `RUN echo "cache test"` to check this. If it doesn't use your cache, then the problem comes from the Jenkins build system, as I said earlier. I don't know any workaround for this but I will try to check anyway.

Comment: see my answer for the main reason of the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

> Using RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ensures your Dockerfile installs the latest package versions with no further coding or manual intervention. This technique is known as “cache busting”. You can also achieve cache-busting by specifying a package version.

Your install instructions bust the cache as explained in the [Best practices for dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run). Any instruction that is not caches will cause all other instructions to be executed again.

Make sure your instructions don't invalidate unless necessary and put all instructions that won't invalidate the cache as high up in your dockerfile as possible. In your case put the curl higher up in the dockerfile and you should be fine.

Hope that helps.

---- UPDATE

Since you updated the question I'll update my answer.

- Every operation after a cache miss will be executed during the build. Put operations that cause cache misses as low in the dockerfile as possible.
- Copying files to your container will cause a cache miss if they changed

The `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` operation is the one causing the problem since it copies all files from that folder. Move that operation as low as possible and repeat with other operations causing problems.

Comment: Thats right. However, I need to install curl and unzip before my download command is using curl and gunzip. What could be the alternative?

Comment: Use a Base image with curl. Or change the command in a way that its not cache busting anymore (i think if you dont update it wont bust the cache). Also you could manually install curl by copying the binary

Comment: Or you could create a new base image in which you install curl and others and based on that image do the download in another dockerfile.

Comment: I think its not these command which are making this big file repeatedly downloadable but the a copy command. I have updated the question.

Comment: The cache is not invalidated because of setting /usr/src/app as a work directory but because of coping source files to this directory. Check the logs. Copy command from base image.

Comment: It clearly state copy /usr/src/app this is cause by the workdir operation

Comment: I tested it bringing the workdir command below the test cache command and it does not work. also the order of that copying does not change.

Comment: Well I think the dockerfile you posted does not fit with the build commands in the output.

Comment: it was due to the base image. See my answer.